# How to add a new row to pandas df that takes data from 2 separate files

Tags: python, pandas

I want to build a pandas dataframe with `columns = ["periods","opens","highs","lows","closes","volumes","consolidating", "5D Perf"]` by looping through all excel files in a folder.

**Periods ... volumes** data values are extracted from files containing "features.xlsx" in the filename and **"consolidating", "5D Perf"** are extracted from files containing "labels.csv" in the filename but I am not sure how to construct the loop. I am using the code below but this way I am getting a broken df.

```
base_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]], columns = ["periods","opens","highs","lows","closes","volumes","consolidating", "5D Perf"])

for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        
        df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        dimensions = df.shape

        period = dimensions[0]-1
        open = df['Open'].tolist()
        high = df['High'].tolist()
        low = df['Low'].tolist()
        close = df['Close'].tolist()
        volume = df['Volume'].tolist()

        base_df[['consolidating', "consolidating", ]] = df[['consolidating', '5D Perf']]
            
        #to_append = [period, open, high, low, close, volume, consolidating, fivedperf]
    
    elif filename.endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)

        consolidating = df['Consolidating'].iloc[0]
        fivedperf = df['5D Performance'].iloc[1]

        base_df[['consolidating', "consolidating", ]] = df[['consolidating', '5D Perf']]
```

If I had show graphically what I want to achieve it would be something like this :

[image]

How can I fix this so that part of the new row is taken from one file and the other part from another file ?

Here are also some sample data files : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f37f68146274beba41d3fd36fec5bd5120220603075831/55edb1

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following:

```
base_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Period","Time","Date","Label1","Label2","Label3"])
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        base_df[['Period', 'Time', 'Date']] = df[['Period', 'Time', 'Date']]
    elif filename.endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        base_df[['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3']] = df[['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3']]
```

Comment: I am getting an error with this as some of the values in these dataframes are lists. I am getting an error "unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: Thats strange, could update your post with a sample of your data and also the error message you get?

Comment: I have edited the main post a bit, I hope the issue is described better now and added some sample data.